# Heroku not installing certain Node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, heroku, lerna

I'm trying deploy a Lerna app on Heroku, but the platform isn't installing the actual Lerna package in the node_modules no matter what I do. I've gotten to the point where I have accessed the app files directly and tried running `npm install lerna@6.0.0` on the server itself. The result is that it installs a number of packages and says that it has added Lerna as well, but actually hasn't.

```bash
~ $ npm install lerna@6.0.0
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN nx@15.6.2 requires a peer of @swc-node/register@^1.4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN nx@15.6.2 requires a peer of @swc/core@^1.2.173 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ lerna@6.0.0
added 16 packages from 7 contributors and audited 1081 packages in 26.529s
found 12 vulnerabilities (2 low, 2 moderate, 6 high, 2 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
~ $ cd node_modules/
~/node_modules $ ls
@pnpm  cross-spawn  get-stream  human-signals  is-stream  isexe  merge-stream  mimic-fn  npm-run-path  onetime  path-key  shebang-command  shebang-regex  signal-exit  strip-final-newline  which
~/node_modules $ cd lerna
bash: cd: lerna: No such file or directory`
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: Why do you have `@pnpm`? Can you add the output for `ls` in the home directory?

Comment: Here is the ls for the home directory:

`Procfile  generate-access-code.html  js  lerna.json  node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json  packages  test-navigation.html`

Comment: I also only have two dependencies (dev dependencies):

`"lerna": "^6.0.0",`
`"lerna-cli": "^5.1.1"`

Comment: Even doing `npm install lerna` to force it to install does nothing. Maybe it's installing globally but I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Does this project contain workspaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the dev dependencies on my app were not installing. Even going into the server and manually running `npm install` for a given package did nothing if it was listed as a `devDependency` in the `package.json`. When I moved all dev dependencies to the runtime dependency list, my issue went away and everything was building as before.

Comment: That's the reason, you should have posted a [mcve]. Heroku sets environment variables to make npm ignore dev dependencies. That's documented and it's also documented how to change this behavior. But without your `package.json` it was impossible to see this problem.

Comment: That's fair. This seems to have been a change after they removed unpaid dynos. I hadn't run into this issue prior and searches for dependencies not installng on Heroku didn't yield anything useful. The errors being output were also too far removed from the issue for me to be sure it was just a matter of dependencies being ignored. I wouldn't have even though dev dependencies being ignored was a reasonable thing to do, since Heroku is often responsible for building the app before deploying.

Comment: I also would have added the minimal reproducible example but that probably would just led me to the answer before I even got here, so I was posting to see if there was something super obvious I was missing. Posting here was honestly a shot in the dark lol

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_, not the the first step.